# Load remote php to send form submission variables, is it possible?

Tags: php, forms, actionscript-3, flash

I have created a form using Flash & actionscript 3. The problem I am having is that I can send the variables to php when stored at the same location as that of the swf file, but if i want to make an android AIR application for the form, I cant address the php file which send me the email. Is it possible to address a remote php file? Please help me, I am stuck at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you stuck with crossdomain.xml.
The idea that first flash load the policy file and check's permissions: can flash access to this server or not. It's a simple security: to prevent flash doing request's where it shouldn't.
For more information just google by keyword `crossdomain.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just had to use the following code.

```
var url:String = "php url";
var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
my_url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
my_url.data = my_vars;
var my_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
my_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
my_loader.load(my_url);
```